# How can the wikipedia api hide their source code?

Tags: php

I have a wiki api site:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

when I save the api.php, I can't see any post or get method behind that.... but I try to write a simple php program.... like this

test.php:

```
<?php echo("testing"); ?>
```

when I updated to server, and save the test.php, people can see my source code. but after I downloaded the api.php, I don't see any php source code from the api.php, but I can pass parameter to the api.php, how can they do so? Thank you.

Comment: This questions covers many complex things. You should take a look at how API works in general. For your file being downloaded with the code, it's a server configuration problem, that differs from wikipedia's. Their execute the PHP code in the files, yours don't.

Comment: You need to associate `.php` files to run under PHP in your server setup. Since you haven't provided what server you're running, we can't really provide much more assistance.

Comment: Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because when you hit that Wikipedia api.php page, you get an HTML document. You're not downloading any Wikipedia source code. You're downloading the output of a PHP script running on a Wikipedia server, and that output happens to be HTML.

As for your test file, since you get the source code instead of "testing", that means your server isn't properly configured and isn't seeing a .php file as a PHP script, and is instead serving up its raw contents.

Answer (score 3):

If you uploaded a file to your server that contained php, and when you view source in your browser you see that php code, that means that your server is not executing your php. It would be parsed out naturally if it was.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the source code of a php file, because when it is accessed on the server it is first interpreted by PHP on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

When a request goes for api.php, the server (most probably Apache) using it's PHP handler, will execute the PHP code and return you the html. Therefore, you will only see the HTML, not the PHP source code.

The reason you are able to view source code of test.php could be because your server doesn't know how to execute PHP code coz it may not be having a PHP handler. Therefore, it is showing the source code.